# Stepping into a GNU function with gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I would like to understand the internal workings of C's memcpy function. Is there a way for me to step into the function using gdb?

Answer (score 5):

Sure. When you get to a `memcpy` call, use `si` (step instruction) to step into the assembly.

You will only get source if you have a debug build of libc and the glibc sources handy, though.

If you want to just see the implementation, check out e.g. [memcpy-ssse3.S](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S;h=9642ceecd90f35a918ed96981836c5a8cdf8f0fa;hb=HEAD) or [memcpy.S](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/memcpy.S;h=d6cd553a266c56c0dca3f00bf5e1dcf071b57b9f;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Nobody says the compiler can't expand the function in line, or replace by something else (e.g. GCC replaces `printf("Some constant string");` with `puts("Some constant string");`)

Comment: @vonbrand: True, but this only happens in rare cases with `memcpy` (really only when copying constant-sized small pieces of data on provably aligned boundaries). It is more common for GCC to *insert* calls to `memcpy`, e.g. when doing struct assignment. (nitpick: it only uses `puts` if the constant string ends with `\n`).

Comment: @nneonneo, currently. You don't know if GCC 5.0 will expand `memcpy` inline each time, or under which exact circumstances. Besides, OP asked for this specific case, but might want to apply the answer to other cases. Or somebody could find this question (and answers) looking for something similar. In C, the compiled program must behave **as if** the function calls and other operations where done as written, in that exact order. If the compiler can _prove_ different code always gives the same results, it is free to replace it.

Comment: Eh, well, if GCC inlines all (or most) of `memcpy`, then using `si` in GDB still lets you see the assembly of `memcpy` :)